# onAuthStateChanged does not work after refresh

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

The following code generate a null user, when I refresh the webpage right after I logged in. Also, the page automatically logout when the access token expires. How do I fix this problem?

```
function initApp() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      console.log("user in onAuthStateChanged:");
      console.log(user);
      userGlobal = user;
      if (user) {
        $("#logindiv").hide();
        $("#userWelcome").text("Welcome, " + user.email);

        $("#logOut").click(function(){
          firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
            $("#logindiv").show();
            $("#testdiv").hide();
          }, function(error) {
            alert(error);
          })
        });

        $("#testdiv").show();

        visiProgcontroller.init(function() {
          visiProgcontroller.makeUIactions();
        })
      }

      else {
        $("#loginButton").click(toggleSignIn);
        $("#logindiv").show();
        $("#testdiv").hide();
      }

    })
  }

  window.onload = function() {
    initApp();
  };
```

**EDIT**: The likely reason is due to the following code. When I comment it out, onAuthStateChanged return non null user. As soon as I put it back, user is null. Any educated guess on why this is blocking/making user null?

```
    visiProgcontroller.init(function() {
      visiProgcontroller.makeUIactions();
    });
```

**SOLUTION**

FOUND the error. I was doing a localStorage.clear(), and I think firebase use this local storage somehow to validate access token.

Answer (score 0):

As you said in your recent edit, your error was picked up after you fired `localStorage.clear()`. For more information on how this may affect your application in different ways, you may want to [look at this article](https://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#the-localstorage-attribute).

Glad you got it to work!